# Identifying a small IDE connector

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, pata, connector, bus

I'm in the possession of the [GENE-9455](http://www.tri-m.com/products/aaeon/gene9455.html):

[image]

At the top left corner there is an IDE connector, however, this is not a normal IDE connector, it's a smaller one. I need to find a cable for this connector. I also have a [hard disk](http://r.ebay.com/MidU4Y) with a connector of the same size which I want to connect to the board.

The pins are approximately 2mm from each other.

**How is this connector size called?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could it be a 44pin Laptop PATA connector? The hard drive you linked is a 2.5" Laptop HDD at least.

Consult this for visual enlightenment (Epic Poster with all kinds of connectors etc.):
http://sonic840.deviantart.com/art/Computer-hardware-poster-1-7-111402099

Adapter:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/2-5-Laptop-SATA-to-44p-PATA-IDE-HDD-Adapter-Converter-/260778737551#ht_2138wt_1012

Comment: Probably indeed. But there isn't any code name for except "Laptop PATA"?

Comment: I think "PATA" and "44pin" is narrowing it down "enough". :-) The poster does not mention anything else, so you might have to search around a bit.

Comment: Aren't there 44-pin PATA connectors for desktops then?

Comment: Nope, those are 40pin. I think the 44pin includes juice. But USB2SATA/PATA adapters often come with a passive adapter from 40pin PATA to your small Laptop PATA. They have a small lead for power from the adapter.

Comment: Ahh, you're right! Now I see, there is no power cable on this HDD indeed. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yep, they bundled the power for laptops and we used to keep small adapter boards around so you could plug the drive into a regular PC IDE connector and power supply.  Of course, PATA is kind of dead these days.